# What are the best practices on repetitive extracting on playwright?

Tags: typescript, playwright

I have to extract the same table from different pages like:

```
class ExtractPage {
    doExtraction() {
      ...
      await page.click('#selector > li[data-period="60"]')
      const extract1 = await page.$$eval('#element', tableElement => {
        const data1 = tableElement.querySelectorAll('.selector1')[0].innerText.trim()
        const data2 = tableElement.querySelectorAll('#id1')[0].innerText.trim()
        const data3 = tableElement.querySelectorAll('#id2')[0].innerText.trim()
        return { data1, data2, data3 }
      })
  
      await page.click('#selector > li[data-period="3600"]')
      const extract2 = await page.$$eval('#element', tableElement => {
        const data1 = tableElement.querySelectorAll('.selector1')[0].innerText.trim()
        const data2 = tableElement.querySelectorAll('#id1')[0].innerText.trim()
        const data3 = tableElement.querySelectorAll('#id2')[0].innerText.trim()
        return { data1, data2, data3 }
      })
    }
}
```

But when i use an external function inside page.$$eval, its undefined, eg:

```
class ExtractPage {
  function extract(element) {    
    const data1 = element.innerText.trim()
    const data2 = element.innerText.trim()
    const data3 = element.innerText.trim()
    return { data1, data2, data3 }
  }
  
  doExtraction() {
    ...
    const extract1 = await page.$$eval('#element', tableElement => {
      return this.extract(tableElement[0]) // This throws an error saying this.extract is not a function
    })
    return extract1
  }
```

I think this happens because the context inside page.$$eval is the browser context and so my method does not exists there, there is any way to pass it into page.$$eval, maybe there is a better solution to register my abstract method to extract data on playwright concepts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't pass a function to `page.$$eval(selector, pageFunction[, arg])`. There's a possibility to pass in an optional `[, arg]`, but it could only be `<...Serializable|JSHandle>`.

Comment: Oh ok, in that case i opted to wrap the call to eval in my method also, there was no lose and it worked, thanks for the info